# Is there a way to save the overlays / polygons on a GMap.NET application so they can be reloaded each time very quickly

Tags: c#, vb.net, polygon, gmap.net

I am writing an application in VB.NET that loads all the suburbs for Australia. There are over 8000 postcodes. I am currently loading them from a SQL CE SDF database file, one SDF file per state. EG NSW, QLD etc. The problem is that it takes way too long to load these polygons and display them on the map. What I would like to be able to do is to load them ones in a development environment then save them for later retrieval so they load much faster than reading in each suburb record one by one from the database files.

I can't seem to see any function built into the GMAP.NET DLL but if any one knows if this is possible or have  suggestion to make the polygons load faster I would be grateful.

The code attached is the procedure that adds the points coordinates to a polygon and the polygon to an overlay and then add the overlay to the map. As I said it takes too long to load.

```
Private Sub AddPolygonToMap(ByVal Description As String, ByVal Suburb As String, ByVal Postcode As String, ByVal State As String, ByVal Latitude As String, ByVal Longitude As String, ByVal Coordinates As String)

        'Dim LineString As String = ""
        Dim PolygonCount As Integer = 0
        Dim CoordinatesSTR As String = Coordinates
        Dim CoordStart As Integer = 0
        Dim StrLen As Integer = 0
        Dim Commapos As Integer
        Dim Tmp2 As String
        Dim KMLDescription As String = Description
        Dim points As List(Of PointLatLng) = New List(Of PointLatLng)
        Dim polygons As GMapOverlay = New GMapOverlay(Suburb)

        Do
            StrLen = CoordinatesSTR.Length
            Commapos = CoordinatesSTR.IndexOf(",")
            If Commapos = -1 Then
                ' end of coords string
                GoTo jump
            End If

            Longitude = CoordinatesSTR.Substring(0, Commapos)
            CoordinatesSTR = CoordinatesSTR.Remove(0, Commapos + 1)
            StrLen = CoordinatesSTR.Length
            Commapos = CoordinatesSTR.IndexOf(",")
            If Commapos = -1 Then
                Latitude = CoordinatesSTR
                StrLen = 0
                GoTo jump

            End If
            Latitude = CoordinatesSTR.Substring(0, Commapos)
            CoordinatesSTR = CoordinatesSTR.Remove(0, Commapos + 1)
            StrLen = CoordinatesSTR.Length

jump:
            points.Add(New PointLatLng(Latitude, Longitude))

        Loop Until StrLen = 0


        Dim polygon As GMapPolygon = New GMapPolygon(points, KMLDescription)
        polygons.Polygons.Add(polygon)
        MainMap.Overlays.Add(polygons)
        polygon.Fill = New SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(35, Color.Red))
        polygon.Stroke = New Pen(Color.Red, 1)
        polygon.IsHitTestVisible = True
        polygon.Name = Description
        polygon.Tag = MainMap.Overlays.Count - 1

        MainMap.ShowCenter = False
        TB_Postcode.Text = Postcode
        TB_Suburb.Text = Suburb
        Me.Refresh()

    End Sub
```

Comment: Generate a SVG file which contains the overlays.  There are tools to help generate the SVG.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but can you elaborate a bit on using SVG files. What tools do you suggest for generating SVG files? And more importantly, if I use SVG files when the polygons are showing on the map using the SVG files will I still be able to use event handlers when clicking on one of the polygons?

Comment: See : https://www.codementor.io/lasithapetthawadu/using-vector-svg-graphics-in-c-net-k9y1ybc8a